# HTTP_USER_AGENT / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent

I have a little web site working with `Node.js`, and I need to do some tuning for mobiles.
For this I would like to access the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. How can I do that?

I have read a few things on the net, but didn't come to a working solution at this point.
One of the thing I went through is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/useragent.

But as soon as I start, adding this to my code:

```
var useragent = require('useragent');
```

I get this error when looking at the site:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The log says:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'useragent'
```

I must obviously not be doing the right thing or doing it wrong.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you installed your package first ?

```
npm install --save useragent
```

Regards

Comment: That was indeed what I was missing.